# How to edit latex file and add images to it

Tags: sectioning, editors, sharelatex

I am new to latex and i have only a basic knowledge of this formal (Mostly i use MS word for preparing documents). My current question is reagrding [this file](https://drop.mx/icol34Fz/). What i am currently doing  is editing **sample.tex** file and replacing appropriate sentences and words. For example

```
\begin{abstract}
Abstract Goes here.
\end{abstract}
```

to

```
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec
mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperdiet mi nec ante. Donec ullamcorper, felis non
sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh lectus placerat pede. Vivamus nunc
nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, veli
\end{abstract}
```

this way i have replaced author,title, abstract and keywords.

but when i tried to replace headings, i was unable to find any codes for that in **sample.tex** but when i compile it i get headings

```
1 Heading on level 1 (section)
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. Nullam nec
mi et neque pharetra sollicitudin. Praesent imperd
```

Can you tell me how i can edit headings and also include figures in this latex file. Currently i am using sharelatex.com for editing latex file

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [full minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: Delete `{\blinddocument` and a closing brace `}` just before `\end{document}`. then add `\section{section}` and contents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template uses `\blinddocument` which has to be removed. Also, better use `align` than  `eqnarray`, unlike the template.  Here is a commented sample code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in, paperheight=10.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    %% amsmath added
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{authblk}
\hypersetup{bookmarks=true,         % show bookmarks bar?
    unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    colorlinks=true}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textbf{International Journal of Mathematical Engineering and Science (IJMES)} \newline Volume 3 Issue 2 (February 2014)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ISSN : 2277-6982 \newline \url{http://www.ijmes.com/}}

\title{More than one Author with different Affiliations}
\author[1]{Author A\thanks{A.A@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author B\thanks{B.B@university.edu}}
\author[1]{Author C\thanks{C.C@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author D\thanks{D.D@university.edu}}
\author[2]{Author E\thanks{E.E@university.edu}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science, \LaTeX\ University}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering, \LaTeX\ University}

\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setcounter{page}{1}



\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract Goes here.
\end{abstract}

\noindent \textbf{Keywords : } Keyword1,keyword2,keyword3.

%% comment the following
%\sloppy
%\nohyphens
%{
%\blinddocument

%% and add the sections and content
\section{My section}
Here we add things. Add a figure here.
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption[Short caption]{This can be very long indeed}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}
You see the image?

\section{Just another section}
Here is another one.

\section{How to add references}
You could refer this way \cite{Mikals2014,Bos2014,GarcíaGonzález201419} or this way \citet{Langlois20141}. The citet command is possible due to the ``natbib'' package and ``IEEETranN.bst'' file.
\section{Tables}
Lets move ahead with tables.

\begin{table}[htb]
     \caption{My first table} % title of Table
  \label{table:t1} % is used to refer this table in the text
  \centering % used for centering table
 \begin{tabular}{l l l l l} % centered columns (4 columns)
 \hline\hline %inserts double horizontal lines
Technique   &H/W  & Distance  & Limitations \\ [0.5ex] % inserts table heading
 \hline % inserts single horizontal line
RSSI     & No              & Few Meters  & Noise, Interference in range\\
ToA      & Yes             & Few Cms     & Nodes synchronization\\
TDoA     & Ultrasound Txr  & Few Meters  & Maximum distance of work\\
AoA      & Set of receivers & few degrees & Work on small sensor nodes\\[0.5ex] % [1ex] adds vertical space
 \hline %inserts single line
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}

We can always refer this table \ref{table:t1} using its label. We can include the equations as well. Both environments viz. begin\{equation\} -- end\{equation\} and begin\{eqnarray\} -- end\{eqnarray\} are available. We personally prefer the later one. An example is given below in equation \ref{eq:e1}.


%% better use `align` than `eqnarray`
\begin{align}
x(t) &=
    \begin{cases}{ll}
        0, & \text{if}\ t<0, \\
        1, & \text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases}
\label{eq:e1}
\end{align}

That's all from us. You may explore as much as you want.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{reference}

%}    %% Remove this

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well I see you're using the template from the zip file you linked to your question. From there you should build your own MWE for ask exactly what's the issue.

From the code of the template aka `sample.tex` for change the headings you should change these lines:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,LO,RE,RO]{}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\textbf{International Journal of Mathematical Engineering and Science (IJMES)} \newline Volume 3 Issue 2 (February 2014)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ISSN : 2277-6982 \newline \url{http://www.ijmes.com/}}
```

Since we don't know what's exactly what you want to put in the headers, you should take a look at the `fancyhdr`package [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) for understand what and how to do it.

In the other hand, as Harish Kumar suggests, in the line 55 you should delete the `\blinddocument` macro and instead of, write your own contents.

Finally, for insert images you should load the `graphicx` package, and you could use the following snippet:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[<option such scale or width>]{<name of the file>}
    \end{center}
    \caption{Caption here} %The text of the caption
    \label{fig:figure1} %a label for cross reference inside the document
\end{figure}
```

But first [read this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures) four understand it better.